# Adding comments to Makefile

Tags: makefile

How do I add comments (with echo) in a `Makefile` so that they're printed when ran?

Answer (score 33):

You should use

```
target:
     @echo "Building!"
```

Note the `@`, which tells Make not to display the command itself.  Without this the output would look like:

```
echo "Building!"
Building!
```

Answer (score 10):

Or, since Make just pushes whatever is in a rule to bash, you could just use a pound to have bash treat it as a comment.

```
Rule:  Dependencies
    # Your Comment
    Command
```

Will output

```
$ make Rule
    # Your Comment
    Command
```

Comment: and how can you do the opposite? put a comment in a makefile that doesn't get printed?

Comment: ended up asking it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360776/how-to-not-print-in-the-output-a-comment-in-a-makefile/18363477?noredirect=1#18363477

Comment: @knocte You can use an `@` before `#`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO, much more readable and produces the exact same result as `@echo "…"`

Comment: make - even GNU make - pushes whatever is in a rule to [sh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217243/which-shell-is-used-in-gnu-make-files), not bash. Unless your system uses bash as sh or - in case of GNU make - you [specify bash explicitly](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since a makefile mostly contains commands to be run when building specific targets, I'd say you use just that: `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

```
all :
    echo "Building!"
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LPATH) $(LIBS) -o $(PROGRAM)
```

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ nmake has the [`!message text...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y32zxwh.aspx) preprocessing directive. I have not used GNU make, so I don't if it has it as weel, but quick search shows it has the [`$(info text...)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) function.

And inside command blocks you can use `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

An imperfect but simple workaround is to add your comments outside the target:

```
Rule:  Dependencies
    Command
# Your Comment
```