# How to NOT print in the output a comment in a makefile

Tags: build, makefile, autotools

I have a makefile that is like this:

```
install:
    @somecommand

    #some explanation for next command
    @lastcommand
```

What happens is that the comment `#some explanation for next command` is being printed when I execute `make install`. How can I make a comment in a makefile that doesn't get printed? Maybe I'm looking for the unix equivalent for the windowsy `echo off`?

(Effectively, the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610623/adding-comments-to-makefile).)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Don't indent the comment — when the line starts with a tab, it is a command that is executed by the shell (and the shell treats the comment as a comment).

Proof of concept (`ss.mk`):

```
all:
    echo "This is the first command"
    # This comment is echoed

# This comment is not echoed
    echo "This is the second command"
```

Sample output:

```
$ make -f ss.mk
echo "This is the first command"
This is the first command
# This comment is echoed
echo "This is the second command"
This is the second command
$
```

Comment: An indented comment prefixed with an `@` will also not be shown, if you *really* want to indent it :-)

Comment: @cbuckley: That is true, but it is a very heavy-weight way of writing a comment because `make` will fork and exec a shell which will scan the comment, deduce that it is a comment, and then exit successfully…unless `make` optimizes for that, which it probably won't.

Comment: Yeah... previously my comment ended with something to the effect of "...but that's probably being ridiculous." Not sure why I removed it!

Comment: The problem with not-indenting-it is that you can't assurely know the tab size of the editor, and so can't align things (like command-line switches) pretty way.

Answer (score 4):

just use `@` at the begin of the line.

```
all:
    @echo "test 1"
    @# echo "test 2"
    echo "test 3"
```

- output:

```bash
$ make

test 1
echo "test 3"
test 3
```